# React state hook behaves differently for different calls

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a simple demo app which pulls some data from GitHub API and shows profile info on cards. Cards can be navigated with either buttons or keypresses.

I wanted to make sure that counter, which I used to send to components as prop to show specific info with `object[count]`, notation resets back to 0 once it reaches the end of array, or skip ahead to 30 (array's size) if you decrement the counter by 1 when the value is 0, so it would loop back to the end of array instead of -1, resulting in an out of bounds error.

This logic works fine with on screen buttons. Keypresses, on the other hand, behave differently even though both buttons and keypresses call the same function.

What am I missing here?

```
function Card(){
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
    const [users, loading] = useFetch("https://api.github.com/users");

    let userCount = loading ? 0 : Number(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(users)).length);

    const navigateNext = () => {
        setCount(count => count === userCount - 1 ? 0 : count + 1);
    }

    const navigateBack = () => {
        setCount(count => count === 0 ? userCount - 1 : count - 1);
    }

    useKey((pressedKey) => {
        if (pressedKey === 39) {
            navigateNext();
        } else if (pressedKey === 37) {
            navigateBack();
        }

    }, {detectKeys: [39, 37]}); // Keycodes for left and right arrow


    return loading ? (      
        <div className="loading">
            <div></div>
        </div> 
        ) : (
        <div className="card animate-bottom">
            <FontAwesomeIcon className="left-arrow button" icon={faAngleLeft} size="3x" onClick={navigateBack} />{" "}
            <div className="content">
                <Profiles users={users} count={count} />
                <Repos users={users} count={count} />
            </div>
            <FontAwesomeIcon className="right-arrow button" icon={faAngleRight} size="3x" onClick={navigateNext} />{" "}
        </div>
    );
}

export default Card;
```

Comment: You can see the repo here:
https://github.com/Ozencb/react-hooks-demo

for live demo:
https://ozencb.github.io/react-hooks-demo/

Check the console log to see how it behaves with buttons and left/right arrow keys

Comment: onClick = {()=>navigateBack()} this should work. You are missing the callback.

Comment: @vinayakshahdeo Yeh, I should have added that but buttons are fine. The problem is with left/right keypresses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you've to add dependencies for users

```
useKey(
    pressedKey => {
      if (pressedKey === 39) {
        navigateNext()
      } else if (pressedKey === 37) {
        navigateBack(userCount)
      }
    },
    { detectKeys: [39, 37] },
    { dependencies: [userCount] },
)
```